# When i fetch Heroku deployed a link, there is an error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, jwt

If i used http://localhost:5000/login everything is working. When i used live link **https://auto-shoroom.herokuapp.com/login** there's the error **POST https://auto-shoroom.herokuapp.com/login 500 (Internal Server Error)**

**The code below with live Heroku link**
.This code aren't working

```
if (user) {
        fetch('https://auto-shoroom.herokuapp.com/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: user.email 
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.token)
                navigate(from, { replace: true });
            });
    }
```

**The code below with localhost link**
.This code is working

```
if (user) {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: user.email 
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data?.token)
                navigate(from, { replace: true });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Answer (score 0):

Check **Reveal Config Vars** in your heroku project setting.
And you need to add KEY and VALUE in Reveal Config Vars.
And that's key value in your .env file.